# Paging 3: RecyclerView remains empty even if data is present

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to implement paging in my android app using the new Paging 3 library. I followed instructions as present in the [sunflower sample app](https://github.com/android/sunflower) by android.

The issue is that after calling `adapter.submitList(it)`, nothing shows up in the recyclerView even if `it` is not empty.

Here is the code populating the recyclerView in Activity class

...

```
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_transactions)
        adapter = UnitSalesAdapter()

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        searchJob?.cancel()
        searchJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
            unitSalesViewModel.getUnitSales(token, start_date, end_date).collectLatest {
                Log.d("flow_log", it.toString())
                adapter.submitData(it)
            }
        }
...
```

Here's my adapter classs

```
class UnitSalesAdapter: PagingDataAdapter<UnitSale, UnitSalesAdapter.ViewHolder>
    (GalleryDiffCallback()) {
    class ViewHolder(@NonNull itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var image = itemView.iv_icon
        var title = itemView.tv_title
        var wallet_type = itemView.tv_wallet_type
        var selling_price = itemView.tv_selling_price
        val profit = itemView.tv_profit
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.unit_sales_item,
                parent,
                false
            )
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val unitSale = getItem(position)
        val profitText = StringBuilder("profit").append(" ").append("+NGN").append(" ")
            .append(unitSale?.profit).toString()
        val spannableText = createSpannableString(profitText, Color.rgb(92, 207, 75))

        holder.title.text = StringBuilder(unitSale!!.examTitle).append(" ").append("Activation")
        holder.wallet_type.text = unitSale.walletType
        holder.selling_price.text = StringBuilder("NGN").append(" ").append(unitSale.sellingPrice)
        holder.profit.text = spannableText

        when (unitSale.walletType){
            "top-up" -> holder.wallet_type.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.topup_badge_bg)
            "referral" -> holder.wallet_type.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.referral_badge_bg)
            "bonus" -> holder.wallet_type.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bonus_badge_bg)
            "direct" -> holder.wallet_type.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.direct_badge_bg)
            else -> holder.wallet_type.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activation_count_bg)
        }
    }

    fun createSpannableString(text: String, color: Int): SpannableString {
        val spannableText = SpannableString(text)
        spannableText.setSpan(
            ForegroundColorSpan(color), 7, text.length,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
        return spannableText
    }
}

private class GalleryDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<UnitSale>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: UnitSale, newItem: UnitSale): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: UnitSale, newItem: UnitSale): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

NOTE:
I have debugged  `unitSalesViewModel.getUnitSales(token, start_date, end_date)` in the first code snippet and it's returning an instance of `PagingData<UnitSale>` as a flow

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!!! I just discovered I hadn't set a layout manager for the recyclerView. All I had to do was

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```